# Family Link: how to set daily limits for one child regardless of which devices he/she uses?

Tags: google-family-link

I can't find a way to set a daily limit to my daughter regardless of her devices. I want her to spend 2h max on screen no matter which device she uses on that day.

Yet she's getting 2h on her tablet and 2h on her smartphone.

Am I missing something? Does Family Link only allow to set device-specific limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how it is supposed to be. See [Set daily limits](https://support.google.com/families/answer/7103340?hl=en&ref_topic=7336331)

> Tip: Daily **limits apply to each Android device or Chromebook your child uses**. For example, if you set a daily limit of 2 hours, your child would get 2 hours of time on **each device.**

(emphasis added)

Comment: Thank you. Is it me or this limitation makes literally no sense? Which parent want to apply limitations on a per-device basis instead of on a per-child basis??

Comment: Google ways are strange

Comment: @drake035 No, it is not just you. This is a weird as it can be. But consider that this problem goes even further. Some old-school children aren't limited to mobile devices only, but also want to use PC. An there you can use Family Link only, if you force them to use Google Chrome. If they intend to use Edge for example, you are in deep a... because there is absolutely no limitation from Google Link there. So you daughter may spend 1 hour on mobile device and 8 hours on PC. Like mine just did. Girls... :)